# MySQL: Add index to an active table

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing

My `_sitecustomers` table has around 67,000 records and after optimizing the site's search I decided I should have indexed 1 or 2 more columns to speed up the query. Is there a way to index an already active table with this many records?

Comment: Yes, you can add the index to a table in use just as you would if the table was not in use. With 87,000 rows, it may take a little time depending on what is contained within the column you're indexing.

Comment: You should've made that a comment so I can mark it as the answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

67k is not a real big number of records. A simple `ALTER TABLE` statement will work:

```
ALTER TABLE `_sitecustomers`
    ADD INDEX `col1` (`col1`),
    ADD INDEX `col2` (`col2`);
```

Comment: Correct me if this is wrong: `ALTER TABLE _sitecustomers ADD INDEX somename (col1 ASC, col2 ASC)`. I'm trying to use 2 columns to make an index. Currently, one of my columns (e.g. col1) already has an index. Do I have to delete that first?

Comment: @enchance No. Multiple indexes can exist.